# Add labels based on geom_errorbar results in r

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, data-visualization, errorbar

I want to visualize data and it's error bars, and i want to add label on based on error bars results, for example i want to add "*" for error between 0 and 1 "**" for errors between 1 and 3 and " *** "  for errors more than 3

i used the command below bellow

```
ggplot(iris[c(2:10,53:70,102:119),], aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, ymin = Sepal.Width - Petal.Width , ymax =Sepal.Width + Petal.Width, group = Species)) + geom_line(aes(linetype = Species)) + geom_point(aes(shape = Species)) + geom_errorbar(width = 0.2)  + facet_wrap(~ Species , labeller = labeller(Task = species2)) + scale_y_continuous(name="Sepal Length and Petal Length") + scale_x_discrete(name="iris data", breaks=c("setosa","versicolor","virginica"), labels=c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")) + labs(title = "Sepal Length and Sepal Width with Petal width errors")
```

and here is the result

[image]

I want to add "*" above all samples where the error bars is between 0 and 1, "**" between all the samples where error bars between 1 and 3 and "***" between all samples where error bars more than 3

Comment: For every point you want a label?

Comment: Yes, in fact i'm using other data with few number of samples i juts wrote an exampel with iris data so everyone can try to execute my command